# User not found after reset password

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, reset-password

After the click on link in email and reset the password it returns "User not found."[image]

userController.js :

```
const resetUserPassword = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // update the user password if the jwt is verified successfully
        const { passwordToken, password } = req.body;
    
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(
            passwordToken,
            process.env.JWT_FORGOT_PASSWORD_TOKEN_SECRET
        );
   
        const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id);

        if (user && password) {
            user.password = password;
            const updatedUser = await user.save();

            if (updatedUser) {
                res.status(200).json({
                    id: updatedUser._id,
                    email: updatedUser.email,
                    name: updatedUser.name,
                    avatar: updatedUser.avatar,
                    isAdmin: updatedUser.isAdmin,
                });
            } else {
                res.status(401);
                throw new Error('Unable to update password');
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error('User not found.');
    }
});
```

userActions.js:

```
export const resetUserPassword = (passwordToken,password) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_RESET_PASSWORD_REQUEST,
      })

      

          
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    }

      const {data} =  await axios.put(`/api/users/reset`,{passwordToken,password},config)

      dispatch({
        type: USER_RESET_PASSWORD_SUCCESS,
        payload: data,
      })

    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message
      dispatch({
        type: USER_RESET_PASSWORD_FAIL,
        payload: message,
      })
    }
  }
```

I'm trying them all, I've also searched on google but I can't figure out where I'm wrong.
Can you help me?
How can I modify the code to make it work without problems?
[image: console error]

In network tab, in response it returns:

````
{"message":"User not found.","stack":"Error: User not found.\n    at file:///C:/Users/Piero/Start2Impact/shop/backend/controllers/userController.js:228:9\n    at asyncUtilWrap (C:\\Users\\Piero\\Start2Impact\\shop\\node_modules\\express-async-handler\\index.js:3:20)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\\Users\\Piero\\Start2Impact\\shop\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)\n    at next (C:\\Users\\Piero\\Start2Impact\\shop\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:137:13)\n    at next (C:\\Users\\Piero\\Start2Impact\\shop\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:131:14)\n    at Route.dispatch (C:\\Users\\Piero\\Start2Impact\\shop\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:112:3)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\\Users\\Piero\\Start2Impact\\shop\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)\n    at C:\\Users\\Piero\\Start2Impact\\shop\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:281:22\n    at Function.process_params (C:\\Users\\Piero\\Start2Impact\\shop\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:341:12)\n    at next (C:\\Users\\Piero\\Start2Impact\\shop\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:275:10)"}```
````

Comment: console log the error that is thrown and add it to your question so that we can understand which part of the code triggered the error.

Comment: Are you able to log `password`, `passwordToken` and `decodedToken` successfully at your server side before interacting with db ?

Comment: It looks like you're hosting your UI on localhost:3000 and you're also hosting your api on localhost:3000. The error tells me that it can't find localhost:3000/api/user/reset. Do you need to host your api on a different port?

Comment: @MichaelHallabrin the error is 400 which the api is throwing (see the outer catch block `res.status(400);` ) so it is reachable. It's not that.

Comment: My bad. The easiest thing to do is to add print or log statements on each line of your controller until you can identify where the problem is. So I would start on the first line of resetUserPassword and see what "req" looks like.

Comment: @MichaelHallabrin I can't see anything from the controller using console.log